# search for a key word in all the Stored Proc's for a given DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to do a global search for a key word in all the Stored Proc's for a given DB?

I used the following but I am unable to get the desired results...

```
SELECT name 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE id IN 
  ( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM syscolumns 
    WHERE name = 'loadStatus' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
  ) 

SELECT name 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE id IN 
  ( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM syscolumns 
    WHERE name like '%loadStatus%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  )
```

Regards
-Vas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this link - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL+Aids/31131/ and see if that helps.

The SP in the linked article was written by Prasad Bhogadi and is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SEARCHFORSTRING @SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(100)
AS
            SELECT  DISTINCT(sysobjects.name)
                FROM 
                sysobjects,syscomments
            WHERE 
                sysobjects.id =     syscomments.id
            AND 
                sysobjects.type = 'P'
            AND 
                sysobjects.category=0
AND
        CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING ,syscomments.text)>0
```

You can use this to create an SP in your database or adapt it for a one-time query.

Comment: Thanks to KM for fixing up the SQL code and making it look presentable.

Comment: heh - tonnes of whitespace, but none for the CHARINDEX comparison

Comment: @rexem, all I did was to highlight the code block and click on the 1s & 0s icon to make the text fixed width, I'm not going to fix the white space and indents...

Answer (score 3):

Only [`sys.sql_modules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081(SQL.90).aspx) contains the whole definition of the procedure. Other views like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` contain a truncated definition.

```
select object_name(o.object_id), m.*
from sys.sql_modules m
join sys.objects o on m.object_id = o.object_id
where o.type= 'P'
and m.definition like N'%<keyword>%'
```

Comment: Didn't know about the 4000 character limit on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Hi Remus!
When running the script getting the error :- 
   Invalid object name 'sys.sql_modules'.
   Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
   Invalid object name 'sys.objects'.

The script was 
    select object_name(o.object_id), m.*
    from sys.sql_modules m
    join sys.objects o on m.object_id = o.object_id
    where o.type= 'P'
    and m.definition like N'%GetExcpCTSInfo%'

Comment: You did mark your question sql-server-2005. Looks like you're testing on SQL 2000.

Comment: You realize I did not hack up MSDN and put in place the documentation of those metadata views. Check @@version, then check if you have some minimal rights in the database (VIEW DEFINITION).