# Find All References to View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've got various databases, and what to be sure I am removing something (a view in this case) that is truly orphaned.  Is the the correct SQL to be using:

```
SELECT r.routine_name, 
       r.routine_definition
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
 WHERE r.routine_definition LIKE '%my_view_name%'
```

The problem with it is that these references aren't picking up declarations in stored procedures, and I don't know what else.

I found the [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364633/search-for-a-key-word-in-all-the-stored-procs-for-a-given-db) I'd remembered, but it's not helping either.  This:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM SYSCOMMENTS t
 WHERE CHARINDEX('my_view_name', t.text) > 0
```

...is close.  I get the body of the stored procedure that I know is using the view, but I'm having trouble getting the actual procedure name.

Comment: Does "sp_depends" not help.
I suppose you'd have to run it on each database.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have one option only.

```
select
    object_name(m.object_id), m.*
from
    sys.sql_modules m
where
    m.definition like N'%my_view_name%'
```

syscomments and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines have nvarchar(4000) columns. So if "myViewName" is used at position 3998, it won't be found. syscomments does have multiple lines but ROUTINES truncates.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is not fully correct. Read this article:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1294

Your method will not return any result if another view uses this view.

SQL Server 2008 has special view (sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities), here it is not that easy.

Comment: If you want to use syscomments and get object name:

SELECT object_name(t.id),t.*
FROM SYSCOMMENTS t
WHERE CHARINDEX('V_MIEJSCE', t.text) > 0

Comment: @LukLed: I didn't want to, just wanted to know what's best to use.  Per gbn's answer, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i guess you can use something like this if your view is used in some stored procedure

```
SELECT *  
FROM syscomments c  
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id =o.id 
WHERE text LIKE '%my_view_name%' AND xtype ='p'
```

Comment: @Neil: The text column is truncated to the 1st 4,000 characters so if the string you are looking for isn't entirely within that 4,000 character limit, the SQL will return a false negative.