# How to find all instances of a procedure (or function) in SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql-server

I modified a procedure and it now takes a greater number of parameters. How can I find every place that the procedure is called so I can update the number of arguments the proc is passed?

I tried this:

```
select * from syscomments where text like '%MODIFIED-PROCEDURE-NAME%'
```

but I'm still finding other places the proc is called that this query did not return.

Comment: The problem with using syscomments is that the text column is nvarchar(4000) and you'll get truncation issues when the text splits between multiple rows. @KM's answer is the better way to go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find All References to View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506082/find-all-references-to-view)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use sys.sql_modules:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(m.object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id)
    FROM sys.sql_modules  m
    WHERE m.definition like '%whatever%'
```

sys.sql_modules.definition is nvarchar(max).  Other similar views have nvarchar(4000) columns, where the text is split over multiple rows.

Comment: +1 - You can use `sp_depends` too but it won't show inter-database dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Get yourself [Red-Gate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) - it's great, it's **FREE** and it just works. It can be used to do exactly what you're looking for! Go grab it - it's worth its weight in gold!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is all inside of SQL server you could just recompile it.

Just create a single script containing all stored procedures and functions.  Run the script.  It'll bomb where the problems are.

Optionally, you could just search the script you created as well.