# SQL- Count occurrences of a specific word within all stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to count the occurrences of a particular word in all of my stored procedures.

i.e. How many times does the word 'place' occur in all of the stored procedures within a specific database?

I was trying to do this using cursors, but I am not getting anywhere!

Comment: please at some of the code you used, then we can get a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you have the .sql files for the stored procs? You could just do string matching on the content....

Comment: SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
    WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%place%' 
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'

Comment: This query gave me the list of sp containing word place...now how do i count the occurences of 'place' in the sp definitions...?

Comment: Use [SYS.SQL_MODULES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506082/find-all-references-to-view)

Comment: using sys.sql_modules returns me user-defined functions too...i want only stored procedures

Comment: Why you want to do this in DB. Just curious :-)

Answer (score 5):

I would use [`object_definition` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx) and [`sys.procedures` view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx) this way:

```
declare @word varchar(128)
set @word = 'place'

select name, (len(object_definition(object_id)) -  len(replace(object_definition(object_id), @word, ''))) / len (@word) as qty
from sys.procedures
where object_definition(object_id) like '%'+@word+'%' and type = 'P'
order by name
```

**Added** after comment, all occurrences of specific word in all stored procedures:

```
declare @word varchar(128)
set @word = 'place'

select sum((len(object_definition(object_id)) -  len(replace(object_definition(object_id), @word, ''))) / len (@word)) as qty
from sys.procedures
where object_definition(object_id) like '%'+@word+'%'
```

Here is working (and updated after comment) example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a759c/7

Comment: Thanks a lot...could u also suggest how to get the total of this..in your example it lists procedure name and qty...what if we want to display only sum of qty? i.e. total occurences of word place?