# Stats for usage of columns in queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, usage-statistics

I am using MS SQL Server 2014. Have some kind of DWH. Also there are around 300 stored procedures which are used for several types of reports. Is there some way to find some kind of stats, which columns from database are used in select clause and how many times, and which columns are used in where clause and how many times ?

Comment: this post might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749105/sql-count-occurrences-of-a-specific-word-within-all-stored-procedures

just counts all occurrances in all stored procedures. so occurrances in the where clause and so on will be counted too

Comment: not helping me to much, because I don't know exact name of all columns, and there are hundreds of them...